# Discretization of continuous attributes using np.histogram - how to apply on a new data point?

Tags: numpy, pandas, scikit-learn, discretization

continuing [How to do discretization of continuous attributes in sklearn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23267767/how-to-do-discretization-of-continuous-attributes-in-sklearn)

After I "learned" my bins from train data, using `np.histogram(A['my_var'])` how do I apply it on my test set? as in which bin is the my_var attribute of each data point? Both my train and test data are in pandas data frames, if it matters.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

oops. it's easy.

```
hist = np.histogram(A['my_var'])
A.loc[:, 'my_bin'] = np.digitize(A['my_var'], hist[1])
```